# how to add @assert in its entity in sf 6?

Tags: symfony

how to add `@Assert` in an entity in sf 6 ?
I have tried this

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

and

```php
#[ORM\Column(length=255)]
/*@Assert\NotBlank()*/
private ?string $nom;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should keep the following use

```
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
```

Since PHP 8.0+ you should use the [attributes](https://php.watch/versions/8.0/attributes)

```php
#[ORM\Column(length=255)]
#[Assert\NotBlank]
private ?string $nom;
```

Only legacy PHP versions (<= 7.4) still need annotations

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(length=255)
 * @Assert\NotBlank
 */
private ?string $nom;
```